# How can I draw text to a view in a circular pattern in Android

Tags: android, textview, android-custom-view

I want to add text in a circle or half circle programmatically, in such a way that instead of having a circle with line edges, the edges are the words. See image for a better explanation.

[image: text circle]

How can I do this in Android, or what resources could I read in order to help me with this problem?

Comment: it will help you http://mindtherobot.com/blog/272/android-custom-ui-making-a-vintage-thermometer/

Comment: [a powerful tool](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Path.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to do this, you will need to draw your text onto a `Canvas`.  Any subclass of `View` is passed a `Canvas` in `onDraw()` that you can use to draw your custom text.  The method `drawTextOnPath()` lets you put text on any `Path` object you choose.  You can create a semi-circle path by creating a new instance and using `addArc()`.

Answer (score 1):

you can Use Below Code. and Make it as you Want your Textview.
Here if you want  Something as Backgroung image then  use   `setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.YOUR_IMAGE);`

```
  public class MainActivity extends Activity {
          @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
           setContentView(new GraphicsView(this));}

      static public class GraphicsView extends View {
         private static final String QUOTE = "text in a half-circle";
         private Path circle;
         private Paint cPaint;
         private Paint tPaint;

     public GraphicsView(Context context) {
      super(context);

      int color = Color.argb(127, 255, 0, 255);

      circle = new Path();
      circle.addCircle(230, 350, 150, Direction.CW);

      cPaint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
      cPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
      cPaint.setColor(Color.LTGRAY);
      cPaint.setStrokeWidth(3);

      // For Background Image
     setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.YOUR_IMAGE);

      tPaint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
      tPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL_AND_STROKE);
     //TextColor you want to set
      tPaint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
      //TextSize you want to set
      tPaint.setTextSize(50);}


      @Override
         protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
         canvas.drawTextOnPath(QUOTE, circle, 485, 20, tPaint);} 
                                            } 
}
```

try it out. hope it will help you.